# If a certain line in my text file is equal to a user inputted text box then

Tags: c#

I've been doing a school project and I have a very poor understanding of C#

If a user inputs a certain name in a textbox and presses a button, it will compare each line of a text file to see if that name already exists in the text file named "NameList".

This is what I have so far and it doesn't seem to be working

```
        string substring = txtSearch.Text;
        string[] list = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("NameList.txt");

        foreach (string s in list)
        {
            if (substring == s) 
            {
                lblUnsafe.Visible = true;
                lblSafe.Visible = false;

            }
            else
            {
                lblUnsafe.Visible = false;
                lblSafe.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

When i input a name that is already in the text file, lblSafe becomes visible, which shouldn't happen.

I'm quite bad at explaining, i apologise, im happy to elaborate further if needed, thanks!

Comment: Seems like you should stop the search as soon as you found a match, otherwise the next iteration of the `foreach` will just overwrite that.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the IF...and a check the values of what your comparing

Answer (score 1):

Your code is partially correct and you might be on the right way here... however in your code, you loop through all names in "NameList.txt", and set the visibility of `lblSafe` and `lblUnsafe` depending on if the current line you are looping on matches the textbox.

However once you match it, you continue looping... so let's find what happens:

User inputs: `John`, and your file contains `Bob, John, Tom`.

Your code does:

- 1st loop: Bob == John? No, then set `lblSafe` to `visible` and `lblUnsafe` to `invisible`
- 2st loop: John == John? Yes, then set `lblSafe` to `invisible` and `lblUnsafe` to `visible`
- 3rd loop: Tom == John? No, then set `lblSafe` to `visible` and `lblUnsafe` to `invisible`

So the end state is that `lblSafe` becomes visible.

What you want to do instead is:

- Set lblSafe to visible and lblUnsafe to invisible before looping
- Then loop through all names

  - If the current loop name matches the textbox text, set lblSafe to invisible and lblUnsafe to visible **and stop looping because we don't care about the rest**

I'll leave the code to you, but it should be pretty easy, and except for a `break` statement to add, it's just reorganizing your own code

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. Assume that the `substring` is not found
2. Loop over file's lines
3. Change visibility and `break` the loop on first finding

Code:

```
    string substring = txtSearch.Text;
    string[] list = ...
  
    // substring is not found yet 
    lblUnsafe.Visible = false;
    lblSafe.Visible = true;

    foreach (string s in list)
    {
        if (substring == s) 
        {
            // substring has been found: we change visibility... 
            lblUnsafe.Visible = true;
            lblSafe.Visible = false;

            // and break the loop: we've found what we wanted   
            break;
        }
    }
```

Usually for such problems we *query* the file with a help of *Linq*:

```
   using System.IO;
   using System.Linq;

   ...  

   // Do we have any line in the file such that...
   lblUnsafe.Visible = File
     .ReadLines("NameList.txt").Any(line => line == txtSearch.Text);

   // Safe is just Not Unsafe
   lblSafe.Visible = !lblUnsafe.Visible;
```